# How to increase the time for timeout exception in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my windows phone app, i'm using HttpWebRequest for getting an image.But i'm getting exception.
When i checked out the stream, ReadTimeout exception has been thrown.

How can i increase the time?? because the data i'm getting is quite large.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there is a `Timeout` property on `HttpWebRequest` that you can set.

Alternatively you can use [Background file transfers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), if your data is large.

Comment: how to set Timeout property for HttpWebRequest??

Comment: Take a look at the example in the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: when i do so, i get an error, __'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Timeout' and no extension method 'Timeout' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)__

Comment: Looks like it is not possible in Windows Phone. So use the Background file transfers or the try the Portable HTTP Client (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx)